# how to tune celery settings so Redis dosent use as much memory? CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES?

Tags: django, redis, celery

kinda a Celery noob here but, I think I have a configuration issue where Celery is putting too much stuff in Redis

my goal is to attempt to reduce or optimize the amount of memory Redis is using, if I can

i have a pretty large Django production thing, where Celery jobs are run "a lot".  In my settings.py I have

```
BROKER_BACKEND = "redis"
```

From a `top -p13907` Redis is using a ton of memory (on the box it's only used by Celery):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13907 redis     20   0 10.5g 3.3g  532 S    0 42.8 109:38.94 redis-server
```

I found this [CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_expires) setting which looks like something I should add to my settings file.

By default, from the documentation it looks like it's set to 1 day (86400 seconds)

Is this what I wanna change?  Or is there more settings I should look into?  Another thing I'm unsure about is if I add it, how should I go about deciding whats a "safe" number of seconds to set it to?

Comment: What Celery version is this?  Configuring the result expiry is smart indeed, but may not be the (only) cause.

Comment: when i do `celeryd --version` at the shell its 2.2.6

Comment: There was a memory leak in version prior to 3.0 that affected Redis.  Every time you start a monitor (celeryev, celerymon, celerycam) it will create a new key in the database, and the events will be copied as many times as you have started monitors.  In Celery 3.0 it uses PUB/SUB instead of persistent lists, which in addition to solving the memory leak, also gives better performance.

Comment: oooo cool thanks!   maybe that's what I'm affected by     ...seems like i got this uber big "ae.undeliver" redis key, and that's something Kombu Celery thing uses (which in turn is something used by those celeryev, celerymon, celerycam things)

Comment: found it i think -->   https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/436   and yeah, when I run the example redis-cli commands in that report, I got the same-ish big memory numbers

Answer (score 0):

i guess maybe your celery caller forget to clean up result and these result will be stored in message queue server until expiration. In celery, you have to call

`r.get()`

to get result and clean it in message queue. if you only access the result without calling this function:

`r.result`

the result would be still holding by message queue server and consume your memory a lot!